# Building NER ensembles

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy, opennlp, ensemble-learning

I am trying to build NER ensembles with models trained on Spacy NER(python), OpenNLP NER (java), StanfordNLP (java) and NLTK(python). I went through this guide for stacking multiple models [here](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/).

I am not sure how to go build a pipeline for this and choosing a meta-classifier.

Since the target is categorical, should I go ahead with choosing the mode for target.